# Force create a record with a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I have 2 models. Job and User. User `has_many :jobs` and Job `belongs_to :user`

Is it at all possible for me to create a Job record with `Job.create(location: "test")` without defining a User? If I try this currently I am getting a `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` error. I assume this is because of the associations.

Any way I can do this without a User ID? I want to add the user_id only later.

Thanks!

Comment: P.S. If this is bad practice then please just let me know kindly thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, *yes* this is possible.

Associations in your models are only there to set [`foreign keys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your datatables. As such, if you wanted to create a `Job` (although it `belongs_to :user`), you'd be able to set all the attributes you desired, and then update `:user_id` later.

Here's a good [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations):

[image]

This shows the datatable structure for the typical `belongs_to` / `has_many` association. Whilst to associate the two objects, you need to have the correct `foreign_key`, you can populate them as you wish.

Comment: Thank's Rich. That makes it nice and clear. Have accepted for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I realise it was a different part of my code not allowing me to do this. You can easily do this.